# Is there an online English translation of Cicero's Phaenomena Aratea?

Tags: reference-request, naturalism, cicero

I was wondering if there's an English/Italian translation of Cicero's Phaenomena Aratea (Prognosis?)? i.e. the translation that he did of Aratus' work.

Thanks!

Comment: Remacle.org has the fragments collected and translated into French (with latin original and places) http://remacle.org/bloodwolf/orateurs/fragm11.htm

Answer (score 2):

Found this, among other options, on googling the same question:

https://opietasanimi.com/2015/12/30/writing-ciceros-aratea-in-the-17th-c/

Answer (score 1):

http://www.bl.uk/catalogues/illuminatedmanuscripts/record.asp?MSID=18480&CollID=8&NStart=2506

Any help?? I'm not sure if it is what you are looking for but hey I hope it will deliver